# Mongodb: Get count of common documents based on the field value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Suppose i have a collection of documents,something like this:

```
{
"itemName":"Burger",
"userId":"25286",
"location":{
       "locationTitle":"Burger king,Delhi"
   }
}

{
"itemName":"Burger",
"userId":"25287",
"location":{
       "locationTitle":"Burger king,Delhi"
  }
}
```

I have to find common items between two users. Item will be common if one of field **itemName** or **locationTitle** have same field value. But one user can have more then one items having same name.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation to group the common items together. The two queries below group entries if they have the same itemName or locationTitle, and adds the userIds to a users array. users array will not contain duplicates, therefore, takes into consideration the requirement that the userId should not be added twice if the same entry appears more than once.

```
db.items.aggregate({
  $group: {
    _id: "$itemName",
    users: {
      $addToSet: "$userId"
    },
    count: {
      $sum: 1
    }
  }
});

db.items.aggregate({
  $group: {
    _id: "$location.locationTitle",
    users: {
      $addToSet: "$userId"
    },
    count: {
      $sum: 1
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work if i will update itemName to "pizza" of first document,it is giving me result me  

{ "_id" : "Burger", "users" : [ "25287" ], "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "pizza", "users" : [ "25286" ], "count" : 1 }

but it should be common because there is same value locationTitle in both documents.

Comment: There are two queries above, one that will do the count on itemName and another on locationTitle. I am not sure if there's a single query that will do both. Let me check

Comment: What will happen in the cases where both the itemName and locationTitle match for two users?

Comment: first of all thanks for effort. So simply it is will be counted as common item and please consider one more case ,there one user can upload item multiple times with same item name or locationTitle.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that in a single query in mongodb. You will have to run the two queries separately in your program and then aggregate the results from the two queries together

Comment: Ok thanks,Could you please update your answer,how i will aggregate result from two queries..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110633/discussion-between-prabjot-singh-and-white-bullet).